# Access other fields in custom validation rules

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, semantic-ui

How to access other form fields in custom validation rules? Having a rule such as

```
$.fn.form.settings.rules.someRule = function(value) {
    let ret;
    //decide if field meets the criteria
    return ret;
};
```

I've been unable to pass second paremeter and the context of the function (`this`) doesn't seem contain the form or the other fields.

Should I just select the DOM element(s) using jQuery or is there some, in my opinion, cleaner way?

Comment: Have you tried `Function.prototype.apply`?

Comment: Can you go into more detail? Not sure how that would help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.fn.form.settings.rules.someRule= function (value, otherFields) {
    let fieldsArray = otherFields.split(",")
    let ret
    //decide if this field (value) meets the criteria
    //decide if other field(s) (fieldsArray) meet(s) the criteria 
    return ret
}
```

And use it like this

```
$(".ui.form").form({
    fields: {
        value: {
            identifier: "value",
            rules: [{
                type: "someRule[otherField, anotherField]",
                prompt: "did not fit criteria"
            }]
        }
    }
});
```